# Curl gives "SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure"

Tags: debian, ubuntu, curl

When I run curl on `https://www.ethics.state.tx.us/data/search/lobby/TEC_LA_CSV.zip` I get a

```
error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

I've tried adding `-2` and `-3` and other things I've seen online, but nothing seems to work. How can I resolve this issue and download this file with curl.

Here is the output from curl below,

```
$ curl -vvvk "https://www.ethics.state.tx.us/data/search/lobby/TEC_LA_CSV.zip"
*   Trying 204.65.203.80:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.ethics.state.tx.us (204.65.203.80) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, handshake failure (552):
* error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

I'm also seeing this when I try to use `-2`,

```
curl: (4) OpenSSL was built without SSLv2 support
```

With `-3`

```
curl: (4) OpenSSL was built without SSLv3 support
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to use the super-secret, Debian/Ubuntu `--ciphers DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1`

```
$ curl --ciphers DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1 -vvvk "https://www.ethics.state.tx.us/data/search/lobby/TEC_LA_CSV.zip"
```

In our case this enables TLS1.2, negotiation of AES128-GCM-SHA256

```
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
```

---

From irc://irc.freenode.net/#curl

```
01:40 < bagder> EvanCarroll: add "--ciphers DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1"
01:41 < EvanCarroll> zomfg.
01:41 < EvanCarroll> Where is that documented.
01:41 < EvanCarroll> nice trick.
01:42 < bagder> that's debian (ubuntu?) making things hard for users by upping that seclevel in the openssl conf
01:42 < bagder> and openssl gives a crappy error message there too, not helping either
```